# How to position a TabBar programmatically

Tags: iphone

I am creating a view controller programmatically which is a `UITabBarDelegate` and contains a `UITabBar`.

```
UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 49)];
[self.view addSubview:tabBar];
```

I don't really want to hardcode the frame values in case the screen resolution changes or I use the view in a different context with a different height, for example.

I'm vaguely aware I can create the tab bar without these values and probe the window and tabbar for height and width to calculate the desired values but I'm struggling to achieve this. What I want to achieve is a tab bar of the standard width and height correctly positioned at the bottom of the enclosing view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] init]; //init with default width and height
tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                          self.view.frame.size.height - tabBar.frame.size.height,
                          self.view.frame.size.width,
                          tabBar.frame.size.height)]; //place it at the bottom of the view
[self.view addSubview:tabBar];
[tabBar release];
```

EDIT:

I've realised thet the size of a newly instantiated UITabBar is zero. Probably your best bet is to use a UITabBarController, as it already sizes your UITabBar accordingly:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview: tabBarController.view];
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I've been trying before, but for some reason the values returned from self.view.frame.size.height or width are all (null)?

Comment: That's curious :-? Try self.view.bounds.size.width and height

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", tabBar); returns '<UITabBar: 0x3d203e0; frame = (0 0; 320 49); layer = <CALayer: 0x3d20720>>', but tabBar.frame or tabBar.bounds return (null). Same goes for self.view.frame or self.view.bounds? I take it this is unexpected behaviour so I should probably pop this out to a new question?

Comment: How do you write the NSLog statement for tabBar.frame ? Try a *NSLog(@"%d", tabBar.frame.size.height);* What do you get?

Comment: I get the value 0 but I guess this is because we're forcing it to a decimal, if it's a string %@ I get '(null)'.

Comment: Well, we are not "forcing" it, the *tabBar.frame.size.height* **is** a decimal, not a string.

Comment: I understand that, but if we specify %d and the value is NULL rather than an integer value, it will evaluate to 0?

Comment: You are right, the size of the newly instantiated UITabBar is zero. Probably your best bet is to use a UITabBarController, as it already sizes your UITabBar accordingly.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this as I'm pushing this 'TabbedViewController' on to a Navigation Controller. I am considering revisiting my application flow logic to avoid this situation.

Comment: for tabBar.frame.size.height we have to use %f , height is in CGFloat